# yii2 gridview search box input automatically clears itself

Tags: php, yii2

I have created a yii2 gridview. But when i enter something in search box of one column, page reloads and what I typed is cleared, that is I cant type anything to search for. Someone please help!

```
Search Model:

$searchModel = new NewsSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize = Yii::$app->params['paginationLength'];
```

Attribute:

```
[
                        'attribute' => 'selectedNews',
                        'header' => 'News',
                        'filter' => yii\bootstrap\Html::textInput('NewsSearch[cat_type]', $searchModel->cat_type, $options = ['class' => 'form-control'])
                    ],
```

Comment: Kindly read this [example](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/#hh9).

Comment: Thanks a lot. @InsaneSkull I missed a simple point.

Answer (score 0):

For all those facing this issue, the problem was that the custom model attributes I used were not validated with safe validation rule. So whenever using custom model attributes, remember to add those to safe validation rule of your search model.